# Почему время принятия ответа отличаются от superuser?

Tags: поддержка, принятые-ответы

Почему время принятия ответа отличаются от superuser ?

На [superuser](https://superuser.com) время принятия ответа 2 минуты. На [ru](https://ru.stackoverflow.com) - 9 минут.

Comment: А что такое "время принятия ответа"?

Comment: _так исторически сложилось_. Уверен это задается в конфигах каждого сайта.

Comment: Серьезно? На MSE пишут только про [15 минут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256359/339911)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На всех сайтах время 15 минут с момента, когда был задан вопрос.
Просто когда ты пытаешься принять ответ, показывается оставшееся время, а не общее.
Ну и для принятия своего ответа надо 2 дня - тоже на всех сайтах.

Comment: Может ТС рядом с чёрной дырой сидит :)